# How to go back in paging after saving an object in NodeJS express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using paging with my NodeJS page.

In ?page=4 , I edit a form, and save it. But then I redirected to
home. How can I handle this?

I am writing       return res.redirect('/products/') after saving the product.

```
exports.update = function(req, res){
  var product = req.product
  product = _.extend(product, req.body)
  product.save(function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      //here, I also tried res.redirect('back') but it stay in the same page
      return res.redirect('/products')
    }
    res.render('products/edit', {
      title: 'Edit Product',
      product: product,
      errors: err.errors
    })
  })
}
```

The template is:

```
  if (pages > 1)
    .pagination
      ul
        != createPagination(pages, page)
```

createPagination function is from view-helpers module.

Comment: You need to show some code and try to explain better.

Comment: What middleware are you using?